# oracle show arabic letter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, arabic

I need to do query like this:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN a.card_reader_status= 'O' 
       THEN 'لاتوجد مشكلة'
       ELSE 'crd_in'
       END AS card_reader
FROM atm
```

How to show the result in Arabic letters in **Oracle** db.

Comment: What is the error with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `,=` and then it will be error free

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN a.card_reader_status='O' 
       THEN 'لاتوجد مشكلة'
       ELSE 'crd_in'
       END AS card_reader 
FROM atm
```